# Create a special version for rebuilt package

Tags: package-management, source-code

I've recently recompiled suPHP from the `apt-get source` to include several commandline options. After building the pacakge it remains at version 0.7.1-1 and aptitude keeps trying to install over the custom one I've built. How can I update the version to reflect something like 0.7.1-1-marco0 - or something similar to that (like how Ubuntu will occasionally place ubuntu0 or ubuntu1 to a version to indicated an edit to the upstream's source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `dch -i` in the source directory to add a new changelog entry. If you update the version line to something like `0.7.1-1ubuntu0+marco1` (the key being the +) it'll sort as being newer than 0.7.1-1 but still older than 0.7.1-1ubuntu1 when Ubuntu releases a security update (since missing security updates is *bad*)

If you really *want* to not get security updates for it, you can lock the version of the package with `sudo aptitude hold suphp`

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is exactly what I was looking for.